# call a function from an array of vectors

Tags: c++, class, vector

In following code, i get an error on line 33. Why? What is the correct syntax?
Surely I made some stupid mistake ... unfortunately I'm trying to better understand the vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class firstClass
{
    public:
        firstClass(int x, int y):sum(x+y)
        {
        }
        void getSum()
        {
        std::cout << sum << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        int sum;
};

class secondClass
{
    public:
        secondClass(int dim)
        {
            obj = new std::vector<firstClass>(dim,firstClass{3,5});
        }
    private:
        std::vector<firstClass>*obj;
};

int main()
{
    secondClass*obj2;
    obj2 = new secondClass(4);
    obj2->(*obj)[0].getSum(); //HERE!
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
error: 'obj' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Even if you do name `obj` correctly, it's private and inaccessible in `main`.  Why would you `new` a `vector`?  Just use a non-pointer `vector` member.

Comment: The syntax for what I think you want to do is `(*obj2->obj)[0].getSum();`, but `obj` is `private`, so you will just get another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The correct syntax for accessing the data member should be:

   ```
   (*(obj2->obj))[0].getSum();
   ```
2. Note that `secondClass::obj` is `private` data member, so you can't access it in `main()`.
3. For code sample you showed, you don't need to use raw pointer and `new` at all.

Comment: Thanks!
1. How do I create "secondClasse" without using "new"?
2. If I had another vector of objects inside object too, what would be the syntax?
3. In truth, the problem was in another program, I wrote the example of quickly so I made a few mistakes.

Comment: @nostyn 1. Just write `secondClass obj2;` then use it like `obj2.obj`. 2. Same as 1.

Comment: I mean the syntax for this: "obj3-> obj2 [1] -> obj1 [3]" You can give me an example?

Comment: @nostyn `((obj3->obj2)[1]->obj1)[3]`? What's the error message?